# C calling a print function in main

Tags: c, arrays, function, printing, struct

I am really new to C and am writing a code that creates a struct with an array of employee information. As you can see in my code, there's employees (there's actually 4 but I cut it down to 1 here for space), and each employee has corresponding info. (Just FYI I left out some stuff in order to save space, like declaring the struct workerT).

I made another function (prntWorker) that should print all the employees and their information, but I don't know how what perimeters to use when I call it in main(). No matter what perimeters I use, CodeBlocks returns that there's too few arguments. I'm sorry I know this is a novice question, but I would greatly appreciate any help!

The goal is "given an array of workerT structs that holds siz elements, print all employee information found in the array element list[indx]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_ROSTER 10 //roster of employees

typedef struct workerT_struct {
    char name[81]; //employee name
    char title[81]; //employee title
    int empID; //unique ID for employee
    int empStatus; 
    int year100_salary; //before-tax salary, in cents
    int year100_401k; //annual contribution to retirement, in cents
    double taxRate; //fraction used to determine payroll taxes
    int month100_paycheck; //monthly paycheck, in cents
} workerT;

void initWorkerArray(workerT list[], int siz);
void prntWorker(workerT list[], int siz, int indx);


int main()
{
    workerT roster[MAX_ROSTER];
    prntWorker(roster, MAX_ROSTER, 0); //FIXME
    return 0;
}

void initWorkerArray(workerT list[], int siz) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        strcpy(list[0].name, "Buggy, Orson");
        strcpy(list[0].title, "Director/President");
        list[0].empID = 1;
        list[0].empStatus = 1;
        list[0].year100_salary = 12015000;
        list[0].year100_401k = 950000;
        list[0].taxRate = 0.45;

        strcpy(list[1].name, "Czechs, Imelda");
        strcpy(list[1].title, "Chief Financial Officer");
        list[1].empID = 2;
        list[1].empStatus = 1;
        list[1].year100_salary = 8020000;
        list[1].year100_401k = 960000;
        list[1].taxRate = 0.39;

        strcpy(list[2].name, "Hold, Levon");
        strcpy(list[2].title, "Customer Service");
        list[2].empID = 6;
        list[2].empStatus = -1;
        list[2].year100_salary = 8575000;
        list[2].year100_401k = 1133000;
        list[2].taxRate = 0.39;

        strcpy(list[3].name, "Andropov, Picov");
        strcpy(list[3].title, "Shipping Coordinator");
        list[3].empID = 7;
        list[3].empStatus = 1;
        list[3].year100_salary = 4450000;
        list[3].year100_401k = 375000;
        list[3].taxRate = 0.31;
    }

    for (i = 4; i < siz; ++i) {
        strcpy(list[i].name, "none");
        strcpy(list[i].title, "none");
        list[i].empID = -1;
        list[i].empStatus = -1;
        list[i].year100_salary = 0;
        list[i].year100_401k = 0;
        list[i].taxRate = 0.0;
    }
    return;
}

void prntWorker(workerT list[], int siz, int indx) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) {
        printf("%s ", list[indx].name);
        printf("%s ", list[indx].title);
        printf("%d ", list[indx].empID);
        printf("%d ", list[indx].empStatus);
        printf("%d ", list[indx].year100_salary);
        printf("%d ", list[indx].year100_401k);
        printf("%lf ", list[indx].taxRate);
        printf("%d ", list[indx].month100_paycheck);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: did you try to `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: Yes I did, it was just one of the things I cut out in order to save space here

Comment: `prntWorker( roster, MAX_ROSTER, 0 )` should work, but your function is confused. It's printing the item at `indx`, and repeating it `siz` times.

Comment: Please post code we can compile... for example no `workerT` definition, and a stray `return` at the bottom or missing `}`.

Comment: You never call initWorkerArray, so there is nothing to print.

Comment: you missed some closing braces.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I updated with all of my code

Comment: Once you fix the previous problems and add the call to `initWorkerArray` like @FredK mentioned, you will want to address the `for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {` loop inside it as you are effectively initializing your data 4 times, then overwrite everything again with zero'd values. I'm sure that's not what you intended!?

Comment: Why `prntWorker` has a `for` loop if you never use the looping var (`i`)? And you must call `initWorkerArray` before attempting to print anything in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issue here:

You never call `initWorkerArray` to initialize the array:

```
int main()
{
    workerT roster[MAX_ROSTER];
    initWorkerArray(roster, MAX_ROSTER);   // add this call
    prntWorker(roster, MAX_ROSTER, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Inside of `initWorkerArray`, the first `for` loop is not needed, as you're updating specific indexes in your array.

You never initialize `month100_paycheck`, either in the second `for` loop or for the initial fields, so this field contains garbage:

```
list[0].month100_paycheck = 0;
...
list[1].month100_paycheck = 0;
...
list[2].month100_paycheck = 0;
...
list[3].month100_paycheck = 0;
...
for (i = 4; i < siz; ++i) {
    ....
    list[i].month100_paycheck = 0;
}
```

Then in `prntWorker`, you're not using the loop index `i` to iterate through the list.  You're using the parameter `indx` instead, which you don't really need:

```
void prntWorker(workerT list[], int siz) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) {
        printf("%s ", list[i].name);
        printf("%s ", list[i].title);
        printf("%d ", list[i].empID);
        printf("%d ", list[i].empStatus);
        printf("%d ", list[i].year100_salary);
        printf("%d ", list[i].year100_401k);
        printf("%lf ", list[i].taxRate);
        printf("%d ", list[i].month100_paycheck);
        printf("\n");    // put a newline at the end for nicer formatting
    }
    return;
}
```

After changing this function, also change the call in `main`:

```
    prntWorker(roster, MAX_ROSTER);
```

After making these changes, you should get the following output:

```
Buggy, Orson Director/President 1 1 12015000 950000 0.450000 0
Czechs, Imelda Chief Financial Officer 2 1 8020000 960000 0.390000 0
Hold, Levon Customer Service 6 -1 8575000 1133000 0.390000 0
Andropov, Picov Shipping Coordinator 7 1 4450000 375000 0.310000 0
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 0
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 0
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 0
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 0
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 0
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your tweaked code. Primarily I called `initWorkerArray()` from `main()`, but removed its loop that initialises the struct 4 times over. I also changed the loop control variable and added a `newline` in `prntWorker()` after printing each record. However the last field `month100_paycheck` is printing absurd values, because it has not been calculated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_ROSTER 10 //roster of employees

typedef struct workerT_struct {
    char name[81]; //employee name
    char title[81]; //employee title
    int empID; //unique ID for employee
    int empStatus; 
    int year100_salary; //before-tax salary, in cents
    int year100_401k; //annual contribution to retirement, in cents
    double taxRate; //fraction used to determine payroll taxes
    int month100_paycheck; //monthly paycheck, in cents
} workerT;

void initWorkerArray(workerT list[], int siz);
void prntWorker(workerT list[], int siz, int indx);


int main()
{
    workerT roster[MAX_ROSTER];
    initWorkerArray(roster, MAX_ROSTER);
    prntWorker(roster, MAX_ROSTER, 0); //FIXME
    return 0;
}

void initWorkerArray(workerT list[], int siz) {
    int i = 0;

    strcpy(list[0].name, "Buggy, Orson");
    strcpy(list[0].title, "Director/President");
    list[0].empID = 1;
    list[0].empStatus = 1;
    list[0].year100_salary = 12015000;
    list[0].year100_401k = 950000;
    list[0].taxRate = 0.45;

    strcpy(list[1].name, "Czechs, Imelda");
    strcpy(list[1].title, "Chief Financial Officer");
    list[1].empID = 2;
    list[1].empStatus = 1;
    list[1].year100_salary = 8020000;
    list[1].year100_401k = 960000;
    list[1].taxRate = 0.39;

    strcpy(list[2].name, "Hold, Levon");
    strcpy(list[2].title, "Customer Service");
    list[2].empID = 6;
    list[2].empStatus = -1;
    list[2].year100_salary = 8575000;
    list[2].year100_401k = 1133000;
    list[2].taxRate = 0.39;

    strcpy(list[3].name, "Andropov, Picov");
    strcpy(list[3].title, "Shipping Coordinator");
    list[3].empID = 7;
    list[3].empStatus = 1;
    list[3].year100_salary = 4450000;
    list[3].year100_401k = 375000;
    list[3].taxRate = 0.31;

    for (i = 4; i < siz; ++i) {
        strcpy(list[i].name, "none");
        strcpy(list[i].title, "none");
        list[i].empID = -1;
        list[i].empStatus = -1;
        list[i].year100_salary = 0;
        list[i].year100_401k = 0;
        list[i].taxRate = 0.0;
    }
    return;
}

void prntWorker(workerT list[], int siz, int indx) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) {
        printf("%s ", list[i].name);
        printf("%s ", list[i].title);
        printf("%d ", list[i].empID);
        printf("%d ", list[i].empStatus);
        printf("%d ", list[i].year100_salary);
        printf("%d ", list[i].year100_401k);
        printf("%lf ", list[i].taxRate);
        printf("%d ", list[i].month100_paycheck);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Program output:

```
Buggy, Orson Director/President 1 1 12015000 950000 0.450000 0
Czechs, Imelda Chief Financial Officer 2 1 8020000 960000 0.390000 1636580
Hold, Levon Customer Service 6 -1 8575000 1133000 0.390000 40370720
Andropov, Picov Shipping Coordinator 7 1 4450000 375000 0.310000 -2
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 50397953
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 2047
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 -1
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 5505360
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 43441
none none -1 -1 0 0 0.000000 4222855
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! The next step is when I'll be calculating the monthly salary, which is why it was left out.

Comment: @peo965 it would be better to init the field in the first place, so that unused records don't have to be calculated from default values.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm just following an assignment's instructions that tell us to do it this way. My professor has a weird way of going about things.